# Is there a geometic intuition for as $\lim_{x \rightarrow 0} \frac{\sin(cx)}{x}=c$ for $c \neq 0$?

Tags: calculus, limits, analysis, soft-question

A common limit introduced in calculus 1 is:

$$\lim_{x \rightarrow 0} \frac{\sin(x)}{x}=1$$

However, for $c \neq 0$ we have that:

$$\lim_{x \rightarrow 0} \frac{\sin(cx)}{x}=c$$

As can be seen by the following argument:

$$\lim_{x \rightarrow 0} \frac{\sin(cx)}{x}= \lim_{x \rightarrow 0} \frac{c\sin(cx)}{cx}$$

Let $y=cx$

$$=\lim_{y \rightarrow 0} \frac{c\sin(y)}{y}=c\lim_{y \rightarrow 0} \frac{\sin(y)}{y}=c$$

I find this fascinating!!! If anyone can give me any intuitive insight into this I'd greatly appreciate it! Thanks in advance.

Comment: Do you mean geometric insight into why the substitution works, using the graphs of arbitrary functions, or do you mean geometric insight into that particular limit (or rather family of limits), using right triangles and cords and circular arcs?

Comment: In general, if, as $x\to0,$  $f(x)/x\to a$ then $f(cx)/x\to ca.$ This has nothing to do with sine.

Comment: It's actually true when $c=0,$ too.

Comment: @Arthur both would be greatly appreciated!!

Comment: @ThomasAndrews Ah, very interesting. Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Many ways to understand this I suppose but the first that comes to my mind is using the Taylor series to see that near the origin, $\sin(cx)$ resembles a line with slope $c$. Take the series for $\sin$:
$$
\sin(y) = \sum_{n=0} \frac{(-1)^n}{(2n+1)!}y^{2n+1}
$$
so that in particular, near $y=0$, $\sin(y)$ behaves like $y$. Taking $y = cx$ and dividing through the series by $x$ gives
$$
\frac{cx}{x} + \sum_{n=1} \frac{(-1)^n}{(2n+1)!}\frac{(cx)^{2n+1}}{x} = c + \sum_{n=1} \frac{(-1)^n}{(2n+1)!}c^{2n+1}x^{2n} 
$$
which is just equal to $c$ when $x=0$.

Comment: "Geometric intuition" is in the title.

Comment: Is a line with slope $c$ not a geometric intuition?

Comment: No line mentioned in your answer. You use the power series for $\sin$ rather than the geometric definition.

Comment: That is the Taylor series of the hyperbolic sine.

Comment: Thank you both for the suggestions/corrections

Comment: Thank you so much this is great!!! I'll probably be giving this a green checkmark but I want to wait to see if I can get more responses if I leave the question open.... Thank you Thank you!!